# Calling Objects from StateMachineBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Just creating this post here as I'm not getting any response in the Unity forum.

I'm not able to make this script work in a State Machine.
I want to make unactive one layer and I want to change one animator parameter.
The problem is that whis script is not compiling.
Any clue about how can this be done?

```
public class SnorHelmetRemove : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    protected GameObject headParent;
    protected Animator animator;
    protected bool checkHelmet;

    private void OnEnable() {
        animator = GameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        bool checkHelmet = animator.GetBool("IsWearingHelmet");
        headParent = GameObject.Find("HeadParent");
    }

    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {

        Debug.Log("Helmet is " + checkHelmet);
        headParent.SetActive(false);
    }

    override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        if (checkHelmet) {
            Debug.Log("Helmet is " + checkHelmet);
            animator.SetBool("IsWearingHelmet",false);
        }   else {
            Debug.Log("Helmet is " + checkHelmet);
            animator.SetBool("IsWearingHelmet",true);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving while trying to compile is in this line `animator = GameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();`
And the error message is this one:

> An object reference is requiered for the non-static field, method or
> property GameObject.GetComponent();

I have followed the Unity guide https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator.GetBool.html and the getObject class is in lower case, but it still don't work if I change this, and I have this error:

> The name 'gameObject' doesn't exists in the current context

Can anybody help me?

Comment: *script is not compiling.* what are the compile errors and on which line. Please [edit] your question to include those details

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using GameObject.getcomponent... it does not know what gameobject you are trying to access. If the animator is on the same object as this script you only need Get component....

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite obvious: [`GameObject.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) is **not** a `static` method. You would rather need an **instance** of a `GameObject` in order to get a component attached to it.

However, in your case - what do you need the cached `animator` and `bool` fields for?

In all relevant state messages you anyway get the animator passed in as parameter and can get and set the bool in that very moment.

```
public class SnorHelmetRemove : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    protected GameObject headParent;

    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        // Cache this one and only fetch it again when needed
        if(!headParent) headParent = GameObject.Find("HeadParent");

        // Get CURRENT bool state
        var checkHelmet = animator.GetBool("IsWearingHelmet");

        Debug.Log("Helmet is " + checkHelmet);

        // I just assume this should use the flag accordingly, otherwise why does it exist at all?
        headParent.SetActive(checkHelmet);
    }

    override public void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        // Get CURRENT bool state 
        var checkHelmet = animator.GetBool("IsWearingHelmet");

        Debug.Log("Helmet is " + checkHelmet);

        // invert the bool
        checkHelmet = !checkHelmet;

        // Write back the new state
        animator.SetBool("IsWearingHelmet", checkHelmet);
    }
}
```